# A naïvely constructed extrapolation of a self-adjoint operator. Is it self-adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real Hilbert space and let $A\colon D(A)\subset \mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ be an unbounded operator. Consider also a [Hilbert triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space) 
$$
\mathcal{H}_+\subset \mathcal{H}\subset \mathcal{H}_+^\star\overset{\rm def}=\mathcal{H}_-$$ 
This means that all spaces are Hilbertian, and all embeddings are continuous and dense, so that the duality pairing of $\mathcal{H}_+$ with $\mathcal{H}_-$ can be realized as an extension of the scalar product of $\mathcal H$).

In this post, an *extrapolation* of $A$ $^{[1]}$ is an unbounded operator defined on $\mathcal{H}$, seen as a dense subspace of the bigger Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_-$:
$$
\overline{A}\colon D(\overline{A})=\mathcal{H}\subset \mathcal{H}_-\to \mathcal{H}_-$$
and such that for all $f\in D(A)$ one has 
$$
Af=\overline{A}f.$$

> Assume that $A$ is self-adjoint and nonnegative. Consider the Hilbert triple $$ D(A)=\mathcal{H}_+\subset \mathcal{H}\subset \mathcal{H}_-=D(A)^\star, $$ where $\mathcal{H}_+$ is equipped with the graph norm $\|f_+\|_{+}^2=\|f_+\|_\mathcal{H}^2 + \|Af_+\|_{\mathcal{H}}^2.$ The relation $$\left\langle  \overline{A}f, g_+ \right\rangle=(f, Ag_+)_\mathcal{H}, \quad \forall f\in \mathcal{H},\ \forall g_+\in \mathcal{H}_+$$ in which $\langle\,,\,\rangle$ refers to the pairing of $\mathcal{H}_-$ and $\mathcal{H}_+$ and $(\,,\,)_{\mathcal H}$ is the scalar product of $\mathcal H$, defines an extrapolation of $A$.
>
> **Is it true that $\overline{A}$ is self-adjoint and nonnegative on $\mathcal{H}_-?$**

---

$^{[1]}$ I am not sure that this is the standard meaning of the word "extrapolation".

Comment: The right setting for this question seems to be the "extrapolation spaces" for evolution equations (see Nagel's paper here:http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1009-14.pdf ).